# Nothing appears in final render

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I'm not sure what I press wrong, but now, my final render doesn't show anything...just stays black.

In Viewport shading everything is visible as it should be...

Any idea? :( .....see screenshots below:
[image]
[image]

Thanks!!!

Two more screenshots with camera view....
[image]

[image]

Found what cause the problem thanks to @RobertGützkow :)
[image]

Comment: Where is your camera located in the scene? Have you checked with Numpad 0 what's visible from the camera's perspective? Have you made sure that the clipping distances for the camera are high enough to capture the scene?

Comment: Yup, I've check everything....if camera isn't set correctly, I shouldn't get correct image in a Viewport, right?

I'll post two more images...one with Num 0....

Comment: Also make sure that you haven't accidentally disconnected or wrongly configured the compositor nodes.

Comment: Also try unchecking the *Sequencer* under *Output Properties* > *Post Processing* > *Sequencer*.

Comment: @RobertGützkow, you were right!!! I have delete somehow Render layers in Compositing. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @Igor Please post the solution as a short answer and accept it. It will help others, plus might get you some sweet rep points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what cause the problem thanks to @RobertGützkow :)

I have delete somehow Render layer in Compositing tab, by accident. noe it's working perfectly ;)

[image]